# Change date format dot instead of slash in Date Range Picker

Tags: jquery, date

is it possible to change the date format from 02/03/2017 to 02.03.2017
dot instead of slash ?
please advice

[link to jquery plugin daterangepicker.com](http://www.daterangepicker.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to change the Date format

```
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
        locale: {
            format: 'MM.DD.YYYY h:mm A'
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks, this one works prefect :)

Answer (score 0):

var date = "02/03/2017"
date = date.split('/').join('.');

Just convert before or after using it.